# Android Market Saying Tablet app isnt compatible?

Tags: android

I just put a android app on the market. to support tablets and cell phones..

But for some reason the market tells me its not availible for my tablet Acer iconia A500.

When my manifest uses this..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="13" /> 
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"  android:smallScreens="false" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!-- Required permission to check licensing. -->
```

These are the only permissions i ask for.. My tablet has all of these. Why is it not working?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this is permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
```

is the culprit as the Acer Iconia isn't a phone but a tablet.

**Update**: I'm almost certain this is the problem after reading this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html#Telephony

Comment: I added <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" /> That is probably exactly why.

Comment: This didnt work =( i added the code in the comment above. It still doesnt show up availible for my device?

Answer (score 2):

See my answer here for more detail in figuring out why this might not be working:
[Android Market filters app - Telephony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420228/android-market-filters-app-telephony/8494994#8494994)

I suggest you check which devices aren't showing as supported in the Market "Show devices" setting.  Check whether other tablets are supported, checking both wifi only tablets (e.g. Xoom) and tablets with telephony support (e.g. some of the Samsung Tabs).

You may have made a mistake with updating your AndroidManifest.xml with the optional telephony setting, did you put the XML in the right place?

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

Also, check your supported "Screen layouts" in your Market account - perhaps your app will only run on smaller screens?  One other thought - I wonder if your minSdkVersion is too early?